# ASP.NET Core 8 OpenID Connect - SUB claim missing on User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I upgraded my ASP.NET MVC Core 7.0 website to ASP.NET MVC Core 8.0. The site uses OpenID Connect identity provider for login.

After update, my `sub` claim went missing in `ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.Claims` collection. I would get:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

when trying to get `sub` claim:

```cs
string userId = User.Identity.FindFirst("sub").Value;
```

Upon further inspection, I noticed that `sub` claim is actually remapped to a different claim:

> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier

This happens despite having default JWT token mappings removed in startup configuration (which worked previously, in ASP.NET Core 7.0 and earlier):

```cs
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

.NET 8.0 has various breaking changes compared to earlier version and they are listed here [Breaking changes in .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/8.0).

In particular, this breaking change is affecting upgrade of the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` from `7.0.*` to `8.0.*`.

One of those changes, detailed here [Security token events return a JsonWebToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events) affects `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.TokenValidatedContext.SecurityToken`, which in turn affects OpenID Connect client behavior. Reason for the breaking change was 30% improvement in performance, according to the Microsoft article.

In order to fix the issue in ASP.NET Core 8.0+ the line:

```cs
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

has to be changed into:

```cs
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

After this change, mapping of OpenID Connect authentication claims will behave same as in earlier .NET versions.

Comment: I never use any handlers and don't have the call to `Clear()` in need to be upgraded (just started a new vanilla project testing the security). I don't get some of the claims into my user's identity neither. Hints on that?

Comment: @KonradViltersten If you don't call `Clear()`, default Microsoft re-mapping is used, instead of preserving original OpenID Connect claim names. I gave you and example what happens with "SUB" claim in the question. But on the other side, if you use OpenID Connect claim-names, you need to re-map `Name` and `Roles`, using `NameClaimType` and `RoleClaimType` of `TokenValidationParameters` OIDC option. It is long and complex topic.

Answer (score -3):

Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

If you apply this solution, it will clear all policies. You can specifically specify the claim you want to clear. Example:

`JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("sub");`

Comment: This is completely off topic. It is Microsoft default mappings that are removed. No policies. This mapping only rename OpenID claims to non-standard, Microsoft format and are not desirable when using OpenID connect. For example, "sub" would be renamed to "nameidentifier".